# JDBC drop table, view, function procedure from Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, drop-table

I want to drop specified oracle tables, views, procedures and functions via Java JDBC Code.

For example, Suppose I've tables T1, T2, T3. Views V1, V2, V3. Procedure P1, P2, P3 and functions F1, F2, F3.

How can I delete these Tables, Views, Procedures and Functions using JDBC?

I've already tried

```
statement.execute("drop table T1");
statement.executeUpdate("drop table T1");
statement.executeQuery("drop table T1");
```

Not working !!!

Comment: Just run the `drop table` statements using `Statement.execute(String)`

Comment: I've already tried it, it is not working.

Comment: `statement.execute("drop table T1");` **will** work. If it's "not working", then **[edit]** your question and add the exact error message you get - "Not working" is not a valid Oracle Error message.

Comment: No any Error message. JDBC program runs successfully without error but it never affects the table from database.

Comment: The code **will** most definitively  drop the table unless an error occurs. Most probably you are not actually catching the error properly in your Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about JDBC in this context. Just run the relevant DDLs with it:

```
Connection conn = /* connect to the database*/
try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
    s.execute("DROP FUNCTION f1");
    s.execute("DROP FUNCTION f2");
    s.execute("DROP FUNCTION f3");

    s.execute("DROP PROCEDURE p1");
    s.execute("DROP PROCEDURE p2");
    s.execute("DROP PROCEDURE p3");

    s.execute("DROP VIEW v1");
    s.execute("DROP VIEW v2");
    s.execute("DROP VIEW v3");

    s.execute("DROP TABLE t1");
    s.execute("DROP TABLE t2");
    s.execute("DROP TABLE t3");
}
```

Comment: @अक्षयपरूळेकर care to elaborate? "not working" doesn't convey too much information, and it would be impossible to help you without the details.

Comment: It never affects the table from Database even after running jdbc code.